# ngFor showing the last element only from array

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

Trying to loop over an array and display the results, but only the last element showing multiple times.

Here is my code.

Making a get request.

```
showItems(id: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}${id}`)
  }
```

Console logging works fine here, I can see the expected results.

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.showItems()
  }

showItems(): void {
    const id: any = []

    this.idFromList.forEach((val: any) => id.push(val.nativeElement.innerText))

    for(let i = 0; id.length > i; i++) {
      this.ItemService.showItems(id[i]).subscribe(data => {this.api_items = data.item.current
        console.log(this.api_items)});
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Price</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of items | filter: searchQuery" >
            <td >
                <a href="" #btn>{{item.id}}</a>
                <a href="">{{ item.name }}</a>
            </td>
             <td *ngFor="let api_item of api_items | keyvalue">
                {{ api_item.value }}
            </td>  
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Tried using fake JSON server, same results.

Comment: Ofc it does, you make a request with ItemService for every item and with every subscription of those requests you overwrite api_items. The storage of api_items in your code is not related to any item.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Quick answer**

Push items in an array instead of replacing its value :

```
api_items = [];

this.ItemService.showItems(id[i]).subscribe(data => {
   this.api_items.push(data.item.current);
});
```

**2) Complete answer**

- As @MoxxiManagarm said, you're replacing `api_items` value at each iteration of your `for` loop.
- You might want to check & use RxJS to handle multiple observables in a cleaner way: for example, by generating an array of Observable to resolve them together.

**3) Ressources & useful links you might want to check for more information**

https://www.learnrxjs.io/